# code to make a ripple effect for imageview

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I am developing one iphone app for aquarium. In that i have to make ripple effect for fish image.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"suck" context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:110 forView:viw_mainfish cache:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

I tried with above coding but its not working. Other effects are working,but i don't no why ripple effect is not working. i am new to developing. So anyone can help me pls.

```
101     pageCurl    
102     pageUnCurl      
103     suckEffect  
104     spewEffect  
105     cameraIris  
106     cameraIrisHollowClose   
107     cameraIrisHollowOpen    
108     genieEffect
```

Comment: Where did you get that list of animation transitions?

Comment: http://www.iphonedevwiki.net/index.php?title=UIViewAnimationState

Comment: Thanks, and standard disclaimer: Use of private API's may prevent you from being approved for the App Store.

Comment: Yes, but I think for those effects it's okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[animation setType:@"rippleEffect" ];
```

OR

```
[UIView setAnimationTransition:(UIViewAnimationTransition)110 forView: viw_mainfish cache:NO];
```